# Grab count of a specific field in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

So I have a schema, and in that schema there is an object called "caseCount" with a Number Value. I simply want to fetch every value for each object of "caseCount" and add it up. Could somebody point me in the right direction? If I need to explain some more, I'm happy to do so. Thank you!

Schema:

```
const Profile = Schema({
    userID: String,
    messageCount: Number,
    caseCount: Number,
    Skins: Array,
});
```

code:

```
const data = Profiles.collection.aggregate([{
      $group: {
        _id: '$id',
        totalCaseCount: { $sum: '$caseCount' }
      }
    }]);
```

Comment: Please share your sample schema.

Comment: Just updated it.

Answer (score 3):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/7TnpQl3tJHt

Use [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) in aggregation query.

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    toatalCaseCount: {  $sum: "$caseCount" }
  }
})
```

---

```
Profiles.collection.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    totalCaseCount: { $sum: '$caseCount' }
  }
  }], function(err, data) {
   console.log(data); // here you'll get your data from the query
});
```

Comment: So I did this, and when I console.logged it, it gives me this

Aggregate {
  _pipeline: [ { '$group': [Object] } ],
  _model: Model { Profiles },
  options: {}
}

Comment: @chai_turtlep add your nodejs code to the question.

Comment: How can I get it to log only the value of "totalCaseCount"?

Comment: @chai_turtlep what are you getting on the log as of now? `data[0].totalCaseCount`

Comment: Hi @TusharGupta-curioustushar You are grouping the records by `$id` instead of `null` in your mongoose code.

Comment: @DheemanthBhat Thank you for pointing that, I didn't notice that, I just added the console.log to OP's code. I'll fix that.